# Extracting bullets and pasting to excel worksheet

Tags: excel, ms-word, format, bullet

Hi I am trying to write a vba macro that takes all the points that follow a bullet in a Ms word document and place each of these in its own cell with each new bullet extract taking the next row following the previous one in the same column. So in effect it has to find the billet select it copy it and paste it in its own cell in a dedicated excel file related to that word doc.

Comment: This isn't a macro-writing service. Search on these terms: _Word VBA get all bulleted text_, _Excel VBA insert text in cells_, and _automate Word from Excel VBA_

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.